# how to Implement slidein effect in windows phone toolkit using xaml and C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="MainLongListSelector" 
                                    Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}"
                                    toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0"

                                    SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged_1">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                            <Image     Source="{Binding ProblemImageFilePath}"
                                       Height="65" 
                                       Width="65" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="10,0,0,0" >
                            </Image>


                            <StackPanel Margin="80,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProblemName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProblemDesc}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Can anyone give the required code to implement slidein effect in windows phone toolkit in the above items

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Generally you don't want to just blatantly ask for code as it will usually result in downvotes and having your question rightfully closed. What you should look for is learning about Storyboard animations, and once you have a specific problem relating to something you've tried on your own first, then this site is an excellent resource. Otherwise, it's like saying "hey I want this, but I don't know how, will you do it for me?" and that's not mutually helpful to anyone.